# Plotting datetime against categorical data (Y-axis)

Tags: python, matplotlib, categorical-data

I'm attempting to plot categorical information against a series of `datetime` values in `matplotlib`. If the categorical data is represented as a string, I can get the plot to work. However, I want the Y-axis to be categorical so that it can be sorted in the correct order.

The following code segment shows what I have so far. In the plot, replace `y` with `y_cat`, and `matplotlib` throws an error:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import calendar, datetime

import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# %matplotlib inline #for Jupyter notebooks

x = pd.date_range('2015/08/01', freq='4M', periods=9)
y = pd.Series(['Good', 'Very Good', 'Very Good', 'Average', 'Average', 'Good', 'Excellent', 'Excellent', 'Excellent'])
y_cat = pd.Categorical(y, categories=['Poor', 'Average', 'Good', 'Very Good', 'Excellent'], ordered=True)

fig, currAX = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 4))
label_format = {'fontsize':12, 'fontweight':'bold'}
title_format = {'fontsize':15, 'fontweight':'bold'}

currAX.plot(x, y, color='crimson', linestyle='-')
#uncomment for error
#currAX.plot(x, y_cat, color='crimson', linestyle='-')

currAX.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.dates.DateFormatter('%Y %b'))

currAX.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
currAX.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
currAX.spines['left'].set_visible(False)

currAX.set_xlabel('Review Period', **label_format)
currAX.set_ylabel('Review Rating', **label_format)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show();

### ERROR:
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I'd like to see the graph with review categories in the Y-axis, sorted from best to worst, top to bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing them as a `list` when it's expecting a `tuple`. Here the code corrected:

EDITED: if you also want to have ordered values on Y-axis you need to specify a number value in order for the plot to know where to place every point. Then replace the INT values with your labels. Here the updated code.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import calendar, datetime

import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# %matplotlib inline #for Jupyter notebooks


x = pd.date_range('2015/08/01', freq='4M', periods=9).tolist()
y = pd.Series(['Good', 'Very Good', 'Very Good', 'Average', 'Average', 'Good', 'Excellent', 'Poor', 'Excellent']).tolist()


### create a conversion DICT
conversion = { \
        "Poor" : 0, \
        "Average" : 1, \
        "Good" : 2, \
        "Very Good" : 3, \
        "Excellent" : 4 \
}
## open a list and insert in it the INT corresponding value
y_converted = []
for v in y :
    y_converted.append(conversion[v])

fig, currAX = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 4))
label_format = {'fontsize':12, 'fontweight':'bold'}
title_format = {'fontsize':15, 'fontweight':'bold'}

### pass as tuple
currAX.plot(x, y_converted, color='crimson', linestyle='-')


currAX.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.dates.DateFormatter('%Y %b'))

currAX.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
currAX.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
currAX.spines['left'].set_visible(False)

currAX.set_xlabel('Review Period', **label_format)
currAX.set_ylabel('Review Rating', **label_format)

### tell matplotlib the ticks and labels to use on Y-axis
currAX.set_yticks( list(conversion.values()) )
currAX.set_yticklabels( list(conversion.keys()) )

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show();
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: The tuple definitely lets you plot the graph. Is there a way to order the Y-axis by the category order? I tried to sort it during the call to plot, but that didn't do it.

Comment: edited my answer with your request, please consider accept and upvote.